# Build long-short portfolio combining two dataframes in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to build a long-short portfolio for currency returns where the long portfolio is a weighted average (50%, 30%, 20%) of the top three ranked currencies by interest rate and the short portfolio is a weighted average of the bottom three ranked currencies by interest rate (20%, 30%, 50%).

In the code below I collect exchange rate data, standardize, rename them and calculate returns.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pandas_datareader as pdr
import edhec_risk_kit_129 as erk 

# create FRED ticker lists containing the exchange rates and interest rates of:
# the Euro area, China, Japan, Canada, the UK, Australia, Switzerland, Sweden, Norway, New Zealand and Denmark
list1=["EXUSEU","EXCHUS","EXJPUS","EXCAUS","EXUSUK", "EXUSAL","EXSZUS", "EXSDUS","EXNOUS","EXUSNZ","EXDNUS"]
list2=["IR3TIB01EZM156N","IR3TIB01CNM156N","IR3TIB01JPM156N","IR3TIB01CAM156N","IR3TIB01GBM156N","IR3TIB01AUM156N","IR3TIB01CHM156N","IR3TIB01SEM156N"
    ,"IR3TIB01NOM156N","IR3TIB01NZM156N","IR3TIB01DKM156N"]

# retrieve exchange rates
exch_rets=pdr.get_data_fred(list1,start="2001-11")
# standardize each currency to currency/USD
exch_rets.loc[:,["EXUSEU", "EXUSUK", "EXUSAL", "EXUSNZ"]]=1/exch_rets.loc[:,["EXUSEU", "EXUSUK", "EXUSAL", "EXUSNZ"]]
exch_rets=exch_rets.rename(columns={"EXUSEU": "EUR","EXCHUS": "CNY","EXJPUS": "JPY","EXCAUS": "CAD","EXUSUK": "GBP" 
                                    ,"EXUSAL": "AUD","EXSZUS": "CHF", "EXSDUS": "SEK","EXNOUS": "NOK","EXUSNZ": "NZD"
                                    ,"EXDNUS": "DKK"})

# standardize each currency to USD/currency
exch_rets=1/exch_rets
exch_rets=(exch_rets/exch_rets.shift(1)).dropna()
```

Similarly, I collect interest rates data for the same currencies.

```
# retrieve interest rates
rates=pdr.get_data_fred(list2,start="2001-11")
# copy columnnames for indexing
rates.columns=exch_rets.columns
# retrieve US interest rate
benchmark_rate=pdr.get_data_fred("IR3TIB01USM156N",start="2001-11")
# calculate monthly returns
benchmark_rate=benchmark_rate/100/12
rates=rates/100/12
rates.dropna(inplace = True)
```

Now I rank the `rates` dataframe by row to obtain the ranked currencies for each day:

```
ranked_rates = rates.rank(1, ascending=True)
```

At this point I would like to create the long-short portfolio for `exch_rets` based on daily `ranked_rates`.

I've tried using `iterrows()` and `melt()` to build it long format but could not go very far.